# "Stick" gameObject to another gameObject after collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently, I am using the following code to make objects stick to other gameObjects:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rb.isKinematic = true;
    gameObject.transform.SetParent (col.gameObject.transform);
}
```

It works perfectly, but it causes many other problems. For example, after colliding, it can no longer detect collisions.

Does someone possess an alternative to this code (which makes a gameObject stick to another one after collision)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start for you, please note that this does not take into account rotation, that i'm sure you will be able to figure out, right? ;)

```
protected Transform stuckTo = null;
protected Vector3 offset = Vector3.zero;

public void LateUpdate()
{
    if (stuckTo != null)
        transform.position = stuckTo.position - offset;
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rb.isKinematic = true;

    if(stuckTo == null 
        || stuckTo != col.gameObject.transform)
        offset = col.gameObject.transform.position - transform.position;

    stuckTo = col.gameObject.transform;

}
```

EDIT: As promised, here is a more advanced version taking rotation into account:

```
Transform stuckTo;
Quaternion offset;
Quaternion look;
float distance;

public void LateUpdate()
{
    if (stuckTo != null)
    {
        Vector3 dir = offset * stuckTo.forward;
        transform.position = stuckTo.position - (dir * distance);
        transform.rotation = stuckTo.rotation * look;
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rb.isKinematic = true;

    if(stuckTo == null 
        || stuckTo != col.gameObject.transform)
    {
        Vector3 diff = col.gameObject.transform.position - transform.position;
        offset = Quaternion.FromToRotation (col.gameObject.transform.forward, diff.normalized);
        look = Quaternion.FromToRotation (col.gameObject.transform.forward, transform.forward);
        distance = diff.magnitude;
        stuckTo = col.gameObject.transform;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get ``error CS0019: Operator `-' cannot be applied to operands of type `UnityEngine.Transform' and `UnityEngine.Vector3'``

Comment: On line `offset = col.gameObject.transform - transform.position;`

Comment: I think you need to check your code because when I run my game, the gameObject just disappears.

Comment: It's because of the LateUpdate() method: `public void LateUpdate()
{
    if (stuckTo != null)
        transform.position = stuckTo.position + offset;
}`

Comment: Write `Debug.Log(transform.position);` into that `if` statement after the `transform.position = stuckTo.position + offset;` line and tell me what it says

Comment: Just numbers, here's one of them: `(7.6, 48.5, 0.0)` I just noticed that my gameObject does not disappear from the scene view, but it disappears from the game view. Why is that?

Comment: +The movement of my gameObject is not executed. It just goes straight to the end point, with no transition at all (in the scene view).

Comment: is you object colliding with anything?

Comment: Yes, my object is colliding with `public Transform stuckTo;` (only in Scene View).

Comment: Haha same problem, only this time the end position is the other side of `public Transform stuckTo;` You probably need to create a completely new piece of code with another way of thinking. :)

Comment: Did I tell you that `public Transform stuckTo;` is moving?

Comment: try what i just changed, i think the offset may be changing on you, and it should be fine that `stuckTo` is moving

Comment: Your code works but does not let me do my gameObject movement, which makes it travel smoothly towards `stuckTo` located in `void Update()` : `actualSpeed = startSpeed;actualSpeed -= slowAmount * Time.deltaTime;
   transform.position += new Vector3 (1, actualSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);`

Comment: I am sure there's a simple fix for this. Right now, it just hits `stuckTo` without my movement.

Comment: yes, put all that inside of an `if (stuckTo == null)`, if you want your object to be "stuck" to something, you cannot be manipulating its `transform.position` at the same time

Comment: The `transform.position` is for before it collides, it uses it to move.

Comment: Where do I put `if (stuckTo == null)`?

Comment: put everything thats manipulating the `transform.position` in your `Update()` method into that `if` statement. like for example all the code you just posted to me in the other comment belongs inside of that `if`

Comment: Same problem, nothing changed.

Comment: so what exactly is happening?

Comment: It goes directly to `stuckTo`'s position without executing my movement first (that permits it to reach `stuckTo` with a transition).

Comment: 1. you've never mentioned anything about this in your question, 2. it goes *to* `stuckTo`'s position, or it goes to the `offset` *from* `stuckTo`'s position?

Comment: It does not have a specific target, it just moves until it collides with something.

Comment: Currently, it takes the position of `offset` from `stuckTo`'s position (without any movement that my own code provides).

Comment: ohh so your saying that without a collision it gets stuck, try changing the first line to `protected Transform stuckTo = null;`

Comment: dont tell me you were setting `stuckTo` via inspector??

Comment: Yes, I did set `stuckTo` via the Inspector.

Comment: What's the problem? What should I normally do?

Comment: well thats why. `stuckTo` is supposed to start off as `null`, just make it `protected Transform stuckTo = null;`, and make `protected Vector3 offset = Vector3.zero;` protected as well

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! I just removed the setting of `stuckTo` in the Inspector and it worked! You solved the problem! :) I have been struggling for ages now... Thank you.

Comment: Just one more thing. How do I deal with rotation? I plan to make my gameObject rotate and then collide.

Comment: oh boy, your talkin about some advanced stuff right there, it is alot more complicated then you might expect, ill try posting something later for that

Comment: Again, thank you very much. If you want to post a lot of code, try uploading somewhere else like in this site: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/ and share the link.

Comment: Okay updated. Let me know if it works i haven't tested it.

Comment: Okay sorry i forgot that order matters when you multiply `Quaternion`s by `Vector3`'s

Comment: lets continue this discussion in the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93833/stick-gameobject-to-another-gameobject-after-collision