# How can I make two objects stick together on collision? (unity 3d ) C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child, collision

In a game I'm making I'm trying to make two Game Objects stick together on collision. I've tried making the first a child of the other, so that when the parent moves the child moves with it. But when I do that the child teleports, and his scale changes( i know it has something to do with World-location/Local-location and World-scale/Local-scale. The child's position and scale change in relative to the parent's position and scale). But I don't know how to solve it.
If anyone could help I would appreciate it.
(it doesn't have to be parent-child related, I just need a clean fix)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Stick" gameObject to another gameObject after collision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396993/stick-gameobject-to-another-gameobject-after-collision)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reparenting is the default solution here. If you expereincing unexpected behaviour with that, its ususally a sign that you are using non-uniform scale somewhere in either of the parent chains. Best practice is to never use scales that have different x, y, z factors. If you need that to change shape of the box, make sure that you scale the box only, and have a dummy parent, to which you reparent your 'attaching' object. Having a non uniform scale somewhere up in the chain (i.e. reparenting to an object that is non uniformly scaled) will skew rotation/scale pairs down the chain, and while this might give the desired effect when only one object is involved, it may bite you when reparenting.

Alternativelty, if that fails to solve your problem for any reason, in newer versions of Unity there is a component called ParentConstraint, which should enable you to achieve the same effect

Comment: I don't know what is uniform scale and what is non-uniform, can you explain? I only want that on collision gameObject1 will stick to gameObject2. I don't want any change in scale or position, the only time I want gameObject1 to move is when it moves with gameobject2. Thanks.

Comment: uniform is when all the three axis (x,y,z) have the same value. non-uniform is when they are different. You can try using the ParentConstraing method, it should work regardless